# Save UIImage to Photo Library Instead of Camera Roll

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, photo

I know how to save an image using standard API calls to the camera roll. I also know that devices without a camera get saved to the Photo Library.

For devices with a camera, how do I save a UIImage to the Photo Library INSTEAD of the camera roll?

Answer (score 5):

You Should try this method provide by IOS SDK,

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, nil, nil, nil );
```

Comment: Thanks! Really great answer!

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know how to do this is with the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum, the quick route is to pass nil to everything but the UIImage parameter.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);
```

Comment: Hmm... I'll see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The photo library is just a placeholder that shows all the pics on your phone, including the camera roll. So, if you deleted a pic from the camera, it would be gone on the photo library. The one in the photo library is not a duplicate; it’s more like a shortcut.
Makes perfect sense. It's like a "favorites" folder. It sources it's info from the main folder.

Comment: This does not seem to be the case. My image is showing up in Camera Roll, but not in Photo Library.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you find. the link shows how to store the images in iPhone Gallery. Check out the link: http://sugartin.info/2012/01/10/permanently-download-image-and-fetch-locally-images/